# `\color` inserts unwanted vertical space in `itemize`

Tags: beamer, color

I'm using beamer, and would like to color certain bullets on certain slides.  Unfortunately, using the `\color` command seems to mess up the vertical spacing in lists.  For example, here are two side-by-side slides.  I would like the slides to have the exact same content and spacing other than the color of the second bullet.  However, latex seems to be inserting extra space around the `\color` command.

[image]

The code to produce these slides is here:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=0pt, text margin right=0pt}
\paperheight=24mm \paperwidth=40mm

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{background}[grid]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\bfseries
\begin{itemize}
  \item Here's a bullet
  \begin{itemize}
    \item And a sub-bullet
  \end{itemize}
\only<2>{\color{structure.fg}}
  \item This will be blue
  \begin{itemize}
    \item On overlay 2
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
{\color{red}\hrule height .5pt}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The beamer `alertenv` environment should handle this, but it works around the problem by calling `\color{.}` even in the event that you are not activating it.  This is not a good solution, because it messes up the vertical spacing in all cases.  (It makes lists look very bad, where there is extra space before bullets just because they happen to turn red on some later overlay.)

I've noticed that I get exactly the same spacing problems if I say `\only<2>{\leavevmode}` instead of changing colors, so presumably what's happening is that the color command is causing a null paragraph to be typeset after the previous nested `itemize` environment.  My question is then how to change the currently active color without contributing any vertical material to the page.

Comment: Just guessing here, but maybe the discussion http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26921318#26921318 is related?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what happens, but the problem seems to be that `\only` is placed between `items`. If you insert inside colorized item, there's no change.

In next code I've introduced `t` option to top align frames and better see where changes start.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=0pt, text margin right=0pt}
\paperheight=24mm \paperwidth=40mm

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{background}[grid]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t,plain]
\bfseries
\begin{itemize}
  \item Here's a bullet
  \begin{itemize}
    \item And a sub-bullet
  \end{itemize}%
\item \only<2>{\color{red}}This will be blue%
  \begin{itemize}
    \item On overlay 2
  \end{itemize}%
\end{itemize}%
{\color{red}\hrule height .5pt}%
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't really answer my question.  If you put the `\color` in the `\item`, then you are already in horizontal mode.  My goal is to build environments like `alertenv` but that don't mess up vertical spacing.  When you say something like `\item<alert@3>`, it wraps an environment around the item, so you need to execute the code in internal vertical mode.

Comment: @user3188445 if you add `\ifhmode HMODE\fi\ifvmode VMODE\fi ` after `\item` (even after `\item\only<2>{\color{..}}`) you will see that immediately after `\item` you are in vertical mode.

Comment: @jfbu That's the problem.  The problem is that `\color` leaves vertical mode, and `\item` starts a new paragraph.  So `\end{itemize}` (vertical mode) followed by `\color` (horizontal mode) followed by `\item` (vertical mode again) causes unwanted space.  I need a way to run `\color` so it doesn't contribute to the current vertical list.

Comment: @user3188445 no, `\color` does not leave vertical mode. It inserts a `whatsit` and this has implications on vertical spacings in certain circumstances. Search for "color + whatsit".

Comment: for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185000/why-does-color-cause-a-vertical-shift

Comment: @user3188445 see also on bottom of page 6 of `grfguide.pdf` (`texdoc color`).

Comment: @jfbu Page 6 is about rotation?  Here:  http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/graphics/grfguide.pdf ?  Oh, I see.  The footnote is currently on page 5.

Comment: @user3188445 bottom of page 5 in your document, sorry. Perhaps an issue of a4 vs usletter.

Comment: @jfbu And there is really no way to work around this?  I even tried `\@bsphack` / `\@esphack`.  I guess the remaining thing to try is temporarily redefining `\item` so as to defer the color change to the next item.  Yuck.

Comment: @user3188445 try to ping David Carlisle ... (meaning: I know of no general way; but specific case can be handled for example if the vertical shift comes from `\addvspace` which couldn't see the previous `\vskip`). AFAIR `\@bsphack` is only for horizontal mode.